# Set JSession id in cookie manager with JMeter

Tags: cookies, jmeter, jsessionid

**Short Description:**

1. I want to set a cookie in my request.

**Test Case:**

1. Start the recording using JMeter.
2. Open the browser and navigate to the login page (I am logged out at this moment, so I am able to see the login page).
3. Record the first request (when opening the page for the first time).

**Whats Should Be Done:**

1. I recorded a script using JMeter. When I open the login page for the first time - it seems that the browser (I think it's the browser) set some kind of cookie (JSESSION_ID).
   [image]
2. When I try to execute the request by myself - there is no cookie data (and there is no JSESSION_ID).
   [image]
3. I need to implement this information because I need to reuse it in another request (I know how to use Regular Expression Extractor).

**The Question:**

1. How can I put this cookie data into the request?
2. Can I use any random string (for example cookie from the first screenshot) for the JSESSION_ID value?

- If not, is there a way to generate a correct JSESSION_ID using JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to the thread group.  The cookie manager `stores and sends cookies just like a web browser`.

If this does not work you may have to extract the JSESSION_ID using postprocessors and pass the variable ${JSESSION_ID} with the headers.

**Note** : Ensure all recorded JSESSION_ID key/value are deleted or JSESSION_ID value is replaced with the ${JSESSION_ID}

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Yes, I was using HTTP Cookie Manager already. What I need was to add data into the "Cookie Data" in the request.

Solution:
The solution that I found is to declare the "Cookie" value into the requested headers.
[image]
As result - I added data into the "Cookie Data" request.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) should automatically handle the cookies coming from the server, to wit extract them from the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header and add them to the next request by creating the relevant [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header, however there might be some constraints preventing JMeter from sending cookies like:

1. Cookie is malformed
2. Cookie is expired
3. The current domain doesn't match the cookie's domain
4. etc.

You might want to add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
```

once done you will see what exactly happens with the cookies, if they're stored, rejected, added, etc. in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

If you don't care about incorrect cookies and don't want to raise an issue for your application you can make JMeter more "relaxed" when it comes to "bad" cookies by choosing less restricting policy like `netscape`

[image]

and adding `CookieManager.check.cookies=false` line to *user.properties* file.

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)

Comment: The issue was that the Jmeter recorder doesn't record correct the requests. One header request was not recordered correctlly.